# How do I get f_type from statfs?

Tags: perl, filesystems, xs

I need to get `f_type` from `statfs`. I tried patching `Filesys::Df`:

```
---
 Df.pm       | 6 +++---
 Makefile.PL | 7 +------
 XS_statfs   | 1 +
 3 files changed, 5 insertions(+), 9 deletions(-)

diff --git a/Df.pm b/Df.pm
index b24bd9c..986082a 100644
--- a/Df.pm
+++ b/Df.pm
@@ -28,7 +28,7 @@ my %fs = ();
    ($block_size) ||
        ($block_size = 1024);

-   my ($frsize, $blocks, $bfree, $bavail, $files, $ffree, $favail);
+   my ($frsize, $blocks, $bfree, $bavail, $files, $ffree, $favail, $ftype);

    #### If open filehandle call fstatvfs or fstatfs
    if(defined(fileno($dir))) {
@@ -36,7 +36,7 @@ my %fs = ();
    }

    else {
-       ($frsize, $blocks, $bfree, $bavail, $files, $ffree, $favail) = _df($dir);
+       ($frsize, $blocks, $bfree, $bavail, $files, $ffree, $favail, $ftype) = _df($dir);
    }


@@ -199,7 +199,7 @@ my %fs = ();
         #        $fs{user_files}  = undef;
         #}

-
+    $fs{type} = $ftype;
    return(\%fs);
 }

diff --git a/Makefile.PL b/Makefile.PL
index 6a89ec4..e91cbb3 100644
--- a/Makefile.PL
+++ b/Makefile.PL
@@ -21,12 +21,7 @@ if($Config{osname} =~ /^MSWin/i) {
    die "You might try Filesys::DfPortable instead.\n";
 }

-#### Check for the existance of statvfs
-if(check_statvfs()) {
-   ####$define .= "-DDF_STATVFS ";
-   copy_xs("XS_statvfs", $xs_file);
-   print "Building with statvfs ....\n";
-}
+# force statfs

 #### Check for the existance of statfs
 elsif(check_statfs()) {
diff --git a/XS_statfs b/XS_statfs
index 856c646..ef801c3 100644
--- a/XS_statfs
+++ b/XS_statfs
@@ -45,6 +45,7 @@ _df(dir)
        PUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVnv((double)st.f_ffree)));
        /* No favail */
        PUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVnv((double)st.f_ffree)));
+       PUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVnv((double)st.f_type)));
    }

    else {
-- 
2.21.0
```

followed by

```
perl Makefile.PL ; make ; perl -Mblib -MFilesys::Df=df -E'say df("/")->{type}'
```

but that crashes

```
panic: XSUB Filesys::Df::_df (Df.c) failed to extend arg stack: base=11d3b10, sp=11d3b50, hwm=11d3b48
```

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: There is  `EXTEND(sp, 7);` at the start of `_df` in the XS file. Try to make a `EXTEND(sp,8);` out of it since you push 8 arguments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike `XPUSH*`, `PUSH*` doesn't ensure there's enough room on the stack.

> **PUSHs**
>
> Push an SV onto the stack. The stack must have room for this element. Does not handle 'set' magic. Does not use `TARG`. See also `PUSHmortal`, `XPUSHs`, and `XPUSHmortal`.
>
> ```
> void PUSHs(SV* sv)
> ```

To ensure there's enough space for the additional value being returned, simply replace

```
EXTEND(sp, 7)
```

with

```
EXTEND(sp, 8)
```

> **EXTEND**
>
> Used to extend the argument stack for an XSUB's return values. Once used, guarantees that there is room for at least `nitems` to be pushed onto the stack.
>
> ```
> void EXTEND(SP, SSize_t nitems)
> ```

---

Tip:

```
PUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVnv((double)st.f_type)));
```

should be

```
PUSHs(sv_2mortal(newSVnv((NV)st.f_type)));
```

That can be shortened to

```
mPUSHs(newSVnv((NV)st.f_type));
```

And that can be shortened to

```
mPUSHn((NV)st.f_type);
```

I realize you're creating a minimal patch and that you're striving for consistency, but this could benefit you and other readers in other situations.